# Button event listener doesnt detect string value from textarea

Tags: javascript, html

I created a textarea where i can enter a value to be shown on the specific day in my calendar. My problem is that i somehow cannot get the string value to be shown on the specific day in my calendar even though i created a button eventlistener where i save the value in a variable when i click it. Below are the relevant code snippets:

```
        <textarea placeholder="Gebe dein Termin ein" id="myTextArea" cols="20" rows="5"></textarea>
        <button id="button">Click</button>
```

```
if(date === today.getDate() && year === today.getFullYear() && month === today.getMonth()){
                text=btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                    document.getElementById('myTextArea').value;
                  });
                console.log(text)  
                cell.innerHTML="GGGG"

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not how it works. You can't just assign a variable with an event listener. Instead do this :

```
var text;
btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  text = document.getElementById('myTextArea').value;
});
console.log(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
text=btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
   document.getElementById('myTextArea').value;
});
```

Does not do what you think it does.

[addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) returns `undefined`. You need to move your logic into the callback you provided.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector("#button");
btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const text = document.getElementById('myTextArea').value;
  console.log(text);
});
```

```html
<textarea placeholder="Gebe dein Termin ein" id="myTextArea" cols="20" rows="5"></textarea>
<button id="button">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the stack overflow community ;)

In addition to [Armedin's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9183974/armedin-kuka) answer you can also do the following

```js
var text;

btn.onclick = function(e){
   text = document.getElementById('myTextArea').value;
}

console.log(text);
```

Both of these techniques have the same effect.

You can find more details about eventlisteners [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)